# Why is it said interface support multiple inheritance when the interface is completely abstract?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I mean we are actually not inheriting anything from the interface. It is in the concrete class that we define what the methods are suppose to do.

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance [see this link for details](http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/)

Comment: Where did you read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces do allow multiple "inheritance" of *behavior*. What Java does not support is multiple inheritance of *state*. An interface does not have state.

You can implement one or more interfaces (implement multiple behaviors) but only extend one class, abstract or not (inherit your state from one other class).

Therefore it could be say that Java has "limited" support for multiple inheritance, but it's not multiple inheritance as it is canonically defined.

Comment: I'm torn by this answer as, while I do like it (maybe just for the prose of it), it still muddles the terminology; Interfaces allow *Polymorphic Behavior*, but not any form of such Multiple Inheritance. Even Traits/Mixins don't fit under how MI is "canonically defined" and those allow state.

Comment: @user2864740 yet you basically inherit this behavior from an interface you implement; I am not fully versed in OO theory either but this is the best parallel I could come up with